# How to restrict user access from all the paths except one?

Tags: 7, users

Suppose you get users from an external service. In the case where the user is locked or has temporary password in the Service, I redirect the user to a change-password page in Drupal and assign to him a "tmp_pass" Role. When the user has that role, he can't see anything but that page.

How should I restrict the access to all paths/menus in one place?

I thought of implementing `hook_menu_alter()` and in the case of "tml_pass" role, assigning a new access callbacks to all the menus, but this is probably not a performance solution.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you look at the [Path access](http://drupal.org/project/path_access) module ?

Comment: yeah had a look at it, it absolutely does what i want.Thanks.It also invokes hook_menu_alter(), my question is : is this the best solution?